# Route "does not exist" in Symfony even though it's declared in main routing file

Tags: php, symfony

Here are the contents of the relevant files :

Contents of `app/config/routing.yml` :

```
horse_route:
    path:   /horse
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Horse:show }


app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Contents of `src/AppBundle/Controller/WalrusController.php` :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class WalrusController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/walrus/red")
     */
    public function walrusRedirect()
    {

      return $this->redirectToRoute('/horse', array(), 301);

    }   
}
```

Contents of `src/AppBundle/Controller/HorseController.php` :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class HorseController extends Controller
{

    public function showAction()
    {
      return new Response('This is a horse.');
    }

}
```

When I type `localhost:8000/walrus/red` in my browser, I get the error message

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/horse" as such route does not exist.
```

It seems that either I did not declare the route correctly in the main routing file, or that I declared it in the wrong place. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your route is called `horse_route` so you would need to use `return $this->redirectToRoute('horse_route', array(), 301);`

Comment: @qooplmao You are absolutely correct. It works now, thanks for answering my stupid question. If you put your comment into an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route is called `horse_route` so you would need to use

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('horse_route', array(), 301);
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove `horse_route:` part from your `app/config/routing.yml`
2. Change your annotation from `@Route("/walrus/red")` to `@Route("/walrus/red", name="walrus_redirect")`
3. Declare a function `/** @Route("/horse", name="horse") */ public function horseAction() { }` for handle `/horse` route

Comment: Looks promising, but when I tried doing as you say I still got the same "horse/ does not exist" message. Maybe I mistyped something. Thanks for your feedback anyway

Comment: Try www.domain.com/horse not  www.domain.com/horse/. Care for "/"

Answer (score -2):

It seem that your controller route is wrong define and for resolve your URL symfony have only /horse route declared.

try this :

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix: /
```